# High performance impact of assigning an iterator's return value in Java?

Tags: java, performance, variable-assignment

I have an implementation of `Iterable<T>` (a variation of a quadtree structure), which I plan to use in a setting where performance with large data sets is critical, so I have been conducting a few tests, with a couple million random entries, running them repeatedly. I experienced an oddity with the following code segment:

```
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     Iterator<A> iter = it.iterator();
     while (iter.hasNext()) {
         iter.next();
     }
 }
 long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println("Total time: " + (end - start));
```

I always got a time between 4000 and 5000 milliseconds. However, when I changed the `while` loop to this:

```
A a = null;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    a = iter.next();
}
```

the time jumps up -- not just slightly, but all the way up to 15 to 16 seconds, with complete consistency. Now this already does not seem dependent on the implementation of `next()`, but upon further investigation, I found that it even happens with a simple `ArrayList`, so I'll post compilable code for that instead:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    static class A {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add a lot of entries
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            list.add(new A());
        }
        // Test it
        A a = null;
        Iterator<A> iter = null;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            iter = list.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                iter.next();
                // Or:
                // a = iter.next();
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total time: " + (end - start));
    }
}
```

The result: an even more unbelievable 30-fold difference. And it happens deterministically, every time.

What possible reason could there be for this? I don't see how a single assignment to an already allocated variable could be anything other than negligible, especially considering that so much else is happening inside `iter.next()`. My only guess is that the `System.currentTimeMillis()` calls are somehow not executed at the proper time, but as for how this is affected by the change, I have no idea.

But even that doesn't quite fit, because the time it takes is noticably much, much longer, especially if I further increase the number of times the `for` loop runs. The garbage collector also should not have anything more to do, as far as I see, since no wasteful, temporary allocations should be happening. It also apparently *is* the assignment of the return value that's critical, since just doing something else in addition to `iter.next()`, like increasing an `int` variable each time, does not have the same adverse effect on execution time.

EDIT: It has been brought to my attention by multiple people that the particular benchmark in my post suffers from many issues that can compromise its results' trustworthiness. I will leave it here for posterity though, or possibly update it later to make it better. That having been said, the phenomenon's most likely cause has been identified in the accepted answer, and I confirmed that eliminating the typecast solved the issue, so despite the benchmark's shortcomings the observation above appears to not have been just a side-effect of those.

Comment: What do you think the JVM does when it sees you're doing nothing with what's returned by `iter.next()`?

Comment: @JacobG. For all the JVM knows, there could be something important happening inside the body of `iter.next()`, so it shouldn't be able to just discard it (at least I would think so). Also, otherwise it would not even be able to tell when to exit the loop.

Comment: I think that a lot of the discrepancies you are seeing will be down to the way that you are benchmarking.  I see no sign that you have attempted to deal with JVM warmup effects, or to isolate the GC and memory allocation effects.  Or even the effects of memory cache sizes.

Comment: @StephenC Admittedly, I am not especially experienced in benchmarking, particularly benchmarking Java. But at the very least the JVM warmup should be negligible, I think, once I scale the parameters (like the 100 in the for loop) up enough that the runtime is in the range of 10s of seconds. And the time scales approximately linearly with that. Also, by the time I start measuring the execution time, most of the objects I use should have already been allocated memory in the heap, is that not right? I did insert a `Thread.sleep()` though, to at least properly eliminate the JVM startup effects.

Comment: I can confirm that result. Even when I run the code several times, the result with assigning `a` is a order or magnitude slower.

Comment: Many (?) JVMs will inline methods that are 64 bytes or less.  It's possible that the `next()` method is being inlined, then the JIT can analyze it and remove most of the code when no assignment is made, even allowing for side effects to still take place.  I think Jacob's intuition (or expert knowledge, or long experience) is likely correct.

Comment: 100 times through the loop is not enough for the JIT compiler to do its job.

Comment: Agreed, and having said what I said.  However: 1) The behavior is apparently real, irrespective of the benchmark, 2) we have at least two plausible explanations for the behavior, and 3) one of them appears to have been confirmed via the OP's actual application rather than his (poor) benchmark.  I propose that we just ignore the benchmark ... unless someone wants to write a better one as an Answer.

Comment: @Taederias - *"I will leave it here for posterity though, or possibly update it later to make it better."* -  Future SO readers (rather than "posterity") would be better served by removing the current benchmark entirely, in my opinion.  A fundamentally flawed benchmark is only ever a distraction.

Comment: @StephenC Fair enough, though the code segment also makes it clear what exactly the issue is, and despite not being a definitive benchmark, one *can* run it to check for themselves. I added the note precisely to warn readers not to consider this an example to follow. I can cut out some of the code though, while still keeping it sufficiently long to actually show the exact question I had.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say code, not code segment, and was talking about the long one, the one that is actually compilable as-is. Anyway, my statement was that a working, copy-pasteable example can be of benefit to readers, together with them being aware of the caveats you (and others) already mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a lot of the discrepancies you are seeing will be down to the way that you are benchmarking. I see no sign that you have attempted to deal with JVM warmup effects, or to isolate the GC and memory allocation effects. Or even the effects of memory cache sizes.

But I think I know what might be going on anyway.

The difference between

```
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
      iter.next();
  }
```

and

```
  A a = null;
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
      a = iter.next();
  }
```

is (obviously!) the assignment.  But the assignment also has a hidden type cast to check that the value returned by `next()` is really an `A`.  (Hint: generic type erasure ...)

But how could the type casts make that much time?

Well, my theory is that this is a combination of the cost of the typecast itself, and a memory cache / locality effect.

In the first example, the iteration is reading references sequentially from a large array.  That is a relatively cache friendly thing to do ... since the array will be a single contiguous block in memory, and the hardware is liable to fetch multiple words into the cache in a single operation.  (Indeed, the JIT *might* even issue cache prefetch instructions ... to avoid pipeline stalls.  (That's a guess ...))

In the second example, between reading each reference, the CPU will also be doing a typecast.  The typecast involves retrieving a class identifier from each `A` instance's header, and then testing to see if it is the correct one.

- Retrieving the identifier from the object header is a memory fetch from a *different* part of memory each time.  The objects may start out contiguous in memory, but even so the spacing is liable to be multiple words apart.  The cache will be far less effective.  And even the fact that both the array and the objects are passing through the same cache will be significant.
- Testing the class identifier may be non-trivial.  If `A` is class not an interface and it has no subclasses, then the runtime should be able to do the equivalent of an `==` test.  Otherwise, the test will be more complicated and more expensive.

---

A second possible explanation is related to code inlining.  If the `Iterator::next()` call is small enough to be inlined, then the JIT compiler's peep-hole optimizer may be able to deduce that some or all of the `next` code is redundant in the assignment-less version of the code.  However, I doubt that it could deduce `next()` is entirely redundant because of the concurrent modification checks.  Eliminating those checks would change the code behavior in edge cases and would be an invalid optimization.

---

In short, it is not difficult to see how the addition of an assignment and the associated hidden typecase could have a significant performance impact, especially on a large data structure.

Comment: Wow, I most certainly did not think of the type cast. I thought that, especially in my own custom data structure, complicated tree traversal operations would be far more costly than anything else, but in hindsight, most of the time all that happens is just increasing an index (maybe a couple times). Anyway, it seems changing the type of `a` to `Object` did completely eliminate the issue (in both cases), so thanks, mystery solved.

Comment: Will explicit cast change the behavior, something like a = (A) iter.next(); ?

Comment: @PavelMolchanov It seems unlikely, considering an explicit cast is just a note for the compiler, essentially, the JVM still needs to do the same thing. (Illustration: if you try to explicitly cast something to an incorrect type, you will get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.) I did check though, and no, that produces the exact same result as the implicit typecast to `A`.

Comment: Does it depend on Java version? Say, will result different if it runs on Java 8, 9, 10?

Comment: @PavelMolchanov - The example will work on any version of Java from Java 5 onwards.  And, I would expect similar performance results.  Prior to Java 5 an explicit typecast is *required* to cast Object to A, and you can't use generics syntax.  But the cost of the typecast will be similar prior to Java 5 too.  The cost of typecast for reference types is inherent to Java.  Without it, Java would not be runtime typesafe.